# CarPlay-connected CLLocation speed is higher than without CarPlay connection on some car models

Tags: gps, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation, carplay

The `speed` property of `CLLocation` that gets returned in the `CLLocationManager`'s `didUpdateLocations` method seems to be higher on some car models when CarPlay gets connected.

This doesn't seem related to CarPlay Navigation support in the app, as a demo-project can reproduce the issue without CarPlay support.

The specific car models where this is confirmed to occur are:

- Volvo XC90
- Ford transit with Sync 3
- Renault Megane IV model 2018 with Rlink2 and latest firmware
- Opel Astra station (2018)
- Ford Focus 2017
- Opel Astra (model K, 2017) — Gets half of GPS speed

An example of the difference:

- Car Speedometer: **120km/h**
- GPS Speed from `didUpdateLocations`: **115km/h**
- GPS Speed from `didUpdateLocations` with CarPlay connected on one of those car models: **130km/h**

Here you can find a demo-project (using NL locale) that reproduces the issue: 
https://github.com/flitsmeister/carplay-speed-problem

Relevant part:

```
override private init() {
    super.init()

    // These settings mimick the settings we have in our production app
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
}

func startLocating() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func stopLocating() {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard lastLocation = locations.first else {
        return
    }

    print(lastLocation.speed) // This property is higher when connected to CarPlay
}
```